# Trying to Make Product Offering Option Selector with Lots of Rules

Tags: matrix, excel-formula

### Summary:

The ultimate use for this workbook is to be able to build a components or bill of materials list. The difficulty comes into play because it is desired to be able to start with any component type and start narrowing down your options on other compatible components to ultimately build a product.

Every component option has it's own rules about which other component options that it is able to interface with. Options within the same component group are mutually exclusive and will never be used together. Each component type will always have one option chosen.

### My Attempts:

Doing a bit of research on the www, I started with trying to create lists for the component options. I keep getting stuck with the rules of compatibility. I chose to call out "0" for component options that are compatible so that I could run a check to see if the sum of parts was greater than 0 (aka something wasn't compatible).

[image: Component List]

[image: Portion of Compatibility Matrix (0 for compatible, 1 for non-compatible)]

I also was starting down the path of using pull down lists under the Data Validation tools, but had trouble when it came to all of the restrictions.

Thank you in advance for any input. I would be happy to elaborate on any part of this request.

An example of how the output might look would be to have the options as pull-downs, but filtered out to not allow you to choose any option that isn't compatible with the other choices that you have already made. Here is an attempt to capture that.

[example of output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqeJG.png)

Comment: Would you show us a desired output for at least two products, that will certainly give a better idea of what you are trying to generate.

Comment: EEM, thanks for that comment. I added an example of what an output table might look like. It doesn't have to be this way, but it was what I originally thought of. I hope that helps.